# Google calendar mule connector is not working

Tags: mule, google-calendar-api

I'm working with Mule and Google Connectors.
I've tried the following code:

```
<mule xmlns:objectstore="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/objectstore" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json"
        xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:google-calendars="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/google-calendars" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
        xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.2"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/objectstore http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/objectstore/1.0/mule-objectstore.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/google-calendars http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/google-calendars/current/mule-google-calendars.xsd">

        <google-calendars:config-with-oauth name="Google_Calendars"
            consumerKey="CUNSUMER_KEY" consumerSecret="CONSUMER_SECRET" doc:name="Google Calendars"
            applicationName="My Project">
            <google-calendars:oauth-callback-config domain="localhost" localPort="8082" path="oauth2callback"
                remotePort="8082" />
            <google-calendars:oauth-store-config objectStore-ref="ObjectStoreBean" />

        </google-calendars:config-with-oauth>

        <spring:beans>
            <spring:bean id="ObjectStoreBean" name="ObjectStoreBean" class="org.mule.util.store.SimpleMemoryObjectStore" />
        </spring:beans>
        <objectstore:config name="ObjectStore" doc:name="ObjectStore" objectStore-ref="ObjectStoreBean" />

        <flow name="authorizationAndAuthenticationFlow">
            <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8080" path="oauth-authorize"
                doc:name="HTTP" />
            <google-calendars:authorize config-ref="Google_Calendars" doc:name="Google Calendars" />
            <objectstore:store config-ref="ObjectStore" doc:name="ObjectStore" key="accessTokenId" overwrite="true"
                value-ref="#[flowVars['OAuthAccessTokenId']]" />
            <set-payload value="You have successfully authorized the connector" doc:name="Set Payload" />
            <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
                <set-payload value="An error has occurred authorizing the connector" doc:name="Set Payload" />
            </catch-exception-strategy>
        </flow>
        <flow name="getAcl">
            <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="get" doc:name="HTTP" />
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
            <enricher target="#[flowVars['accessTokenId']]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
                <objectstore:retrieve config-ref="ObjectStore" key="accessTokenId" defaultValue-ref="#['']" doc:name="Get AccessToken" />
            </enricher>
            <expression-filter expression="#[flowVars['accessTokenId'] != '']" doc:name="Is Access Token Set" />
            <google-calendars:get-calendar-by-id id="CALENDAR_ID" config-ref="Google_Calendars" doc:name="Google Calendars" accessTokenId="#[flowVars['accessTokenId']]" />
            <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON" />
        </flow>

    </mule>
```

I can get the OAuth2 Authorization just fine, but when I try to get a Calendar I get:

```
Exception stack is:
1. com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedInteger.asUnsigned(I)Lcom/google/common/primitives/UnsignedInteger; (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError)
  com.google.api.client.util.Data:81 (null)
2. com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedInteger.asUnsigned(I)Lcom/google/common/primitives/UnsignedInteger; (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError). Message payload is of type: NullPayload (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:32 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedInteger.asUnsigned(I)Lcom/google/common/primitives/UnsignedInteger;
    at com.google.api.client.util.Data.<clinit>(Data.java:81)
    at com.google.api.client.util.FieldInfo.<init>(FieldInfo.java:131)
    at com.google.api.client.util.FieldInfo.of(FieldInfo.java:104)
    at com.google.api.client.util.ClassInfo.<init>(ClassInfo.java:181)
    at com.google.api.client.util.ClassInfo.of(ClassInfo.java:92)
    at com.google.api.client.util.ClassInfo.<init>(ClassInfo.java:175)
    at com.google.api.client.util.ClassInfo.of(ClassInfo.java:92)
    at com.google.api.client.util.GenericData.<init>(GenericData.java:79)
    at com.google.api.client.util.GenericData.<init>(GenericData.java:61)
    at com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpRequest.<init>(JsonHttpRequest.java:69)
    at com.google.api.services.calendar.CalendarRequest.<init>(CalendarRequest.java:44)
    at com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar$Calendars$Get.<init>(Calendar.java:1372)
    at com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar$Calendars.get(Calendar.java:1358)
    at org.mule.module.google.calendar.GoogleCalendarConnector.getCalendarById(GoogleCalendarConnector.java:273)
    at org.mule.module.google.calendar.processors.GetCalendarByIdMessageProcessor$1.process(GetCalendarByIdMessageProcessor.java:119)
    at org.mule.security.oauth.process.ProcessCallbackProcessInterceptor.execute(ProcessCallbackProcessInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.security.oauth.process.RefreshTokenProcessInterceptor.execute(RefreshTokenProcessInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.mule.security.oauth.process.RefreshTokenProcessInterceptor.execute(RefreshTokenProcessInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.security.oauth.process.ManagedAccessTokenProcessInterceptor.execute(ManagedAccessTokenProcessInterceptor.java:75)
    at org.mule.security.oauth.process.ManagedAccessTokenProcessInterceptor.execute(ManagedAccessTokenProcessInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.security.oauth.process.ManagedAccessTokenProcessTemplate.execute(ManagedAccessTokenProcessTemplate.java:42)
    at org.mule.module.google.calendar.processors.GetCalendarByIdMessageProcessor.doProcess(GetCalendarByIdMessageProcessor.java:105)
    at org.mule.devkit.processor.DevkitBasedMessageProcessor.process(DevkitBasedMessageProcessor.java:88)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:40)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:102)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.construct.DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.process(DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.java:54)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelope...
*******************************************************************************`
```

I've tried with Mule 3.5.2 and the Google Calendar Connector v.1.1.1 and also the v.1.2.4 but still not working

**Edit:**

Actually I found out that Google Connectors are referring to guava-12.0.jar but the Mule Server Library refers to guava-16.0.1.jar, so I think when I'm running the app the actual jar that is been use is guava-16.0.1.jar where the method doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Please show the full stack trace so we can see what's using this long deprecated and remove method from `UnsignedInteger`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some code somewhere (see my comment below your question) depends on pre-15.0 Guava, where the deprecated `asUnsigned` has been removed from `UnsignedInteger`.

You can try to force Guava to `14.0.1` by adding this into your project's `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>14.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This downgrade may of course break other things elsewhere, but it's worth a shot (until we figure out where is the code that requires this removed method and file an issue with the relevant project).

**EDIT**: It turns out Mule brings a more recent version of Guava to the classpath. So you'll need to configure the application classloader to use the version of Guava you embed in the app zip itself. Add the following in `mule-deploy.properties`:

```
loader.override=-com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedInteger
```

Reference: https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/35X/Classloader+Control+in+Mule

Comment: Hello, I've changed the version of guava than I'm using but I got the same result.

Comment: Are you sure the Guava `14.0.1` is on the classpath / packaged in the Mule app? If yes, this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Wait: it does make sense, Mule itself brings its own version of Guava on the classpath. This is probably what wreaks havoc with the Google connector. Let me review my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I also add the -com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedLong